1st conditional future perfect sentence
I have the following sentence: When you … (finish) the e-mail, send it to the manager. I don't know how to complete it - logical thing would be to add "finish" since it's the 1st conditional sentence. However, to make things difficult, my teacher told us not to use "finish" form.
I've been thinking that maybe I should put "will have finished" there, but thought it won't match, because you are not allowed to use "will" in that part of conditional.
What do you guys think? I'd appreciate your help.

(To people voting to close: This is in no way a "proofreading" question. A clear area of concern is identified, and the asker's concerns are well explained.)

"When you finish the email ..." is fine but more natural sounding (especially in speech) would be "When you've finished the email". In what context did your teacher say not to use "finish"? In your sentence "when" could be replaced with "after" rather than "if". The clear implication is that finishing the email is something that will definitely happen in the future.

There was just a comment "not 'finish'" at the end of the sentence.

@Jacca92 ... I think your teacher was trying to get you to find an alternative to "finish" rather than saying it was wrong. "When you've finished ..." is the best alternative. It emphasises that the finishing of the email will be in the past before you can send it.

Yes, that's true. We were supposed to find the alternative. I think I was overthinking a little bit. Thanks!
